# Autosave content of TinyMce editor on change event (with laravel 7)?

Tags: ajax, laravel, tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to autosave the content of tinyMce editor

I'm using tinmce version 5.2.2 with laravel V7

tinymce configuration in app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('tinymce/themes/silver');
require('tinymce/plugins/image');
require('tinymce/plugins/code');
require('tinymce/plugins/save');


import tinymce from 'tinymce';
tinymce.init({

        selector:'textarea#inputQuestionTitle',
        height:400,
        setup: function(editor) {
                editor.on('Change Keyup', function () {
                            editor.save();
                            //tinyMCE.triggerSave()   <-- also tried
        });
    }
```

With following View

```
@extends('dashboard.layout')
@section('content')

<form id='addQ' action="{{route('questions.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
@csrf
  <div class="form-row align-items-center "  >
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inputQuestionTitle">Title</label>
        <textarea  name="title" class="form-control mb-2 " id="inputQuestionTitle" placeholder="Question Title"> </textarea>
      </div>
  </div>


         <div class="form-row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add new category </button>
     </div>




</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#addQ').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
      var frmdata = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(frmdata); 
    });
  });
</script>
@endsection
```

Outputs

[image: Output of view and title field returns null]

I had using jquery to show input request with console.log
As showed in output title field does not returns any value

Please tell me how i autosave the content of tinymce editor and send it with input request ..

I had also tried to tinymce.triggerSave() before serialize() method of  ajax so that input request will take tinymce content but not works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to update the textarea via the `triggerSave()` or `save()` methods while someone is editing the content I would just place `tinymce.triggerSave()` at the very beginning of the function that submits the page.  This will ensure that the `triggerSave()` is called directly before you grab the content from the textarea.

Comment: I had also tried that but textarea not updated and returns null

Comment: can u know any other method to sortout this problem